# jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium Self Test Error

Tags: php, magento, solr

I am using magento 1.8 and using [Plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/solr-search-based-on-solarium.html) for search and follow all the instructions for installation from [wiki](https://github.com/jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium/wiki/Installation-Instructions).

Everything looks fine and working except self test which give the output like this

```
Connection to Solr              Success  
Ping Solr                       Success  
Check Solr version              Success  
Inserting test entry in Solr    Success  
Search for test entry           Success  
Test Autocomplete               Success  
Test Correction of Typos        **FAILED**   
Test "Did You Mean..."          **FAILED**   
Deleting test entry from Solr   Success
```

can you guys help me out in this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by copying/replacing `solrconfig.xml` from `jeroenvermeulen/magento-solarium`  to `solr\apache-solr\solr\collection1\conf` and change

```
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
```

to

```
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text</str>
```

in solrconfig.xml

it's working for me, if any of you find same problem than use the information above or ask me.